# The fastest and most efficient way to get max number from a list of numbers

Tags: python, runtime

How can I improve the code and make it the fastest and most efficient way to take 10 numbers from the user, and then calculate the highest number from the list ? It can be anything, Pythonic, etc..

I have this code, and I want you please to improve it.

```
numbers = []
for _ in range(11):
    numbers.append(input('Enter Num: '))

result = max(numbers)
print(result)
```

**I have not included the program execution time because I'm taking inputs.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most compact way I could think of:

```
result = max([input("Enter num: ") for _ in range(11)])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply:

```
max = 0
for _ in range(11):
    next = input('Enter Num: ')
    if next > max:
        max = next
print(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = []
for _ in range(11):
    numbers.append(input('Enter Num: ')
numbers.sort() 
print("Largest element is:", numbers[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = raw_input("Enter 10 numbers seperated by a comma (IE 1,2,3,..,..): ")
numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers.split(",")]
results = set()
for _ in range(len(numbers)+1):
    results.add(_)
print(max(results))
```

Demo:

```
 >>> numbers = raw_input("Enter 10 numbers seperated by a comma (IE 1,2,3,..,..): ")
Enter 10 numbers seperated by a comma (IE 1,2,3,..,..): 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
>>> numbers = [int(i) for i in numbers.split(",")]
>>> results = set()
>>> for _ in range(len(numbers)+1):
...     results.add(_)
...
>>> results
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
>>> print(list(results).sort())
None
>>> print(max(results))
10
>>>
```